# Error: ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ⊘ (U+2298)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX

Tags: unicode, input-encodings

I have got a Problem. I added the pages and editions in Mendeley for my literature (Right klick and "update Details"). After compiling, I got the error:

> ```
> ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ⊘ (U+2298)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX.See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... ...}rd P, Warren G, Morrison PT, Nordenskj⊘
> ```

I thought that the paper (Warren et al.) will be the reason because of its letters. But after deleting `\cite{…}` of this source in my text, the error is still remaining. I have no idea, what to do. If you need a minimimal Latex example, I can post it, too. Before adding the pages, I had no problems at all. Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Well, Mendeley seems at fault here, because it uses ⊘ (U+2298) instead of ø (U+00F8).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you know how I can Change this?

Comment: Search in your bib file for this "rd P, Warren G, Morrison PT, Nordenskj⊘" and just remove/replace the last character., Then clear the files with extension ".bbl" and ".aux" in the projects folder and rerun LaTeX (or pdfLaTeX or whatever you are using)

Comment: Can you please show the publication data so that we can experiment with Mendeley?

Comment: As of today https://doi.org/10.1038/368258a0 has "Nordenskj⊘ld" with `U+2298` instead of `U+00F8`. So this might not be Mendeley's fault, but rather an issue with the data provided by the publisher. Still, the solution is the same. Replace  `Nordenskj⊘ld` with `Nordenskjøld` (i.e. `⊘` [`U+2298`] with `ø` [`U+00F8`]). After you have done that you may have to delete all temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, ...) and recompile with LaTeX, BibTeX/Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX, because otherwise the faulty content might persist in the temporary files and cause harm even though the source (`.bib`) is fixed

Comment: Can you open the bib file that's produced by Mendeley and replace all instances of `⊘` with `{\o}`?